# How do I auto redirect from my root path?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, path, redirect

I'm using Django and Python 3.7. I'm having an issue trying to redirect from my homepage ("/") to another path. I want the default root path to redirect to "/trending".  I tried this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'/$', redirect_to, {'url': '/trending'}), 
    path('trending', views.trending, name='trending'),
]
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
name 'redirect_to' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

Link your path to a view function definition and return the redirect.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', redirect_view)
    # ... more URL patterns here
]
```

views.py

```
def redirect_view(request):
    response = redirect('/trending/')
    return response
```

Comment: Ok, I did everything that you said, but I get the error, "name 'redirect_view' is not defined".  I put that "redirect_view" function at the top of my views.py file (after the imports)

Comment: Did you import the views file in your models.py? from appname import views. Then views.redirect_view

Comment: Yeah I did.  But no matter, when I replaced your line with 'path('', views.trending),' everything worked the way I wanted to so I went ahead and upvoted you since you got me goign in the rigiht direction.

Comment: No error -- everything is working fine with the 'path('', views.trending),' line.

Comment: Is it getting you where you want to be? Does it redirect at all? If it does, the problem could lie in the extra "/" in the redirect.